# Get List of VHDs in an AzureRM Storage Account

Tags: azure

I'm using the rest api to communicate to AzureRM. How do I get the list of vhd files in a storage account?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us: 1) Which REST API are you using: Azure Resource Manager or Azure Storage? and 2) Are you looking for all VHDs in a storage account or VHDs associated with a particular VM?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Example](http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/61325) that shows how to use the Azure Storage Rest api to get the list of VHDs in a storage account.